# Discrepancy while implementing quicksort in Python

Tags: python, function, methods, quicksort

Here is my implementation of quicksort in Python:

```
def quicksort(alist):
    if len(alist) <= 1:
        return alist
    else:
        pivot = alist[len(alist)//2]
        alist.remove(pivot)
        alist1, alist2 = partition(alist, pivot)
        return quicksort(alist1) + [pivot] + quicksort(alist2)

def partition(alist, pivot):
    alist1 = []
    alist2 = []
    for e in alist:
        if e <= pivot:
            alist1.append(e)
        else:
            alist2.append(e)
    return (alist1, alist2)
```

This implementation works fine. But look at the lines 6 and 7 which are `alist.remove(pivot)` and `alist1, alist2 = partition(alist, pivot)` respectively. If I try to merge these two lines into one line of code by rewriting the 7th line as follows: `alist1, alist2 = partition(alist.remove(pivot), pivot)`, then my code doesn't work. I get the following TypeError:

`TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable`

Would like to know why do I run into this error?

Comment: As an aside, the `remove` line is completely useless and makes the code substantially slower. Rewrite `partition` to exclude the pivot instead.

Answer (score 2):

The `remove` method does not return the modified list, and in python, if a function doesn't return anything, it "returns" `None`

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> r = a.remove(2)
>>> r == None
True
```

Answer (score 1):

`alist.remove(pivot)` is not returning the actual list, `list.remove` returns `None` in Python

Answer (score 1):

You get the error because `alist.remove(pivot)` does not return a list.

It doesn't return anything (`None`) just removes `pivot`from your list.

Therefore what you end up passing to you `partition` method is a `Nonetype` object instead of a list.